# Call to a member function setPassword() on array - Get & update entity doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Well, I must be doing something syntactically wrong, I'll explain my little problem.

I have a symfony listener that retrieves the user's email, and must update an info of this user.

For that, I thought I'd get the user with the repository, then update with -set...() But no... I have this mistake:

Call to a member function setPassword() on array

I understand that the repo returns an array to me, but then how to make it return the modifiable entity?

Here's my listener:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\EventPriorities;
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use App\Entity\ForgotPassEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ViewEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Twig\Environment;

class ForgotPasswordSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {


    public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer,Environment $environment,UserRepository $userRepository,EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->twig = $environment;
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::VIEW => ['SendMail', EventPriorities::POST_WRITE],
        ];
    }



    public function SendMail(ViewEvent $event): void
    {
        function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
            $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
            $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
            $randomString = '';
            for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
            }
            return $randomString;
        }

        $forgotPassHandler = $event->getControllerResult();
        $method = $event->getRequest()->getMethod();

        if (!$forgotPassHandler instanceof ForgotPassEvent || Request::METHOD_POST !== $method) {
            return;
        }

        $user = $this->userRepository->findBy(array('email'=>$forgotPassHandler->getUserEmail()));

        if($user == null){
            return;
        }

        $generatePass = generateRandomString();

        dump($generatePass);

        $user->setPassword($generatePass);
        $this->em->flush();

        $message = (new \Swift_Message('Reset password OptaKPI'))
        ->setFrom('kpi@support.com')
        ->setTo($forgotPassHandler->getUserEmail())
        ->setBody(
            $this->twig->render(
                // templates/emails/registration.html.twig
                'emails/forgotPass.html.twig',
                [
                    'userEmail' => $forgotPassHandler->getUserEmail(),
                    'generatePass' => $generatePass
                ]
            ),
            'text/html'
        );
        try {
            $this->mailer->send($message);
        }
        catch (\Swift_TransportException $e) {
            dump($e->getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

I must be missing something... But I confess I don't master symfony very well...

Thank you!

PS : Sorry for my english ^^'

Answer (score 1):

You call `findBy` method that returns a collection of users, but you need to `findOneBy` that will return a one user

Answer (score 0):

Hello so I'm new and I might be wrong but I can see it is syntactically wrong as  the repo isn't properly connected and hence not returning with the modified values.

Again I maybe wrong but hope that helped a bit

Comment: The repo works, if I dump $user it returns the user I'm looking for, but as an array :/

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i'm wrong, but what's happening there, is that your setPassword expect a string.But your function generateRandomString(); is probably returning an array and not a string.

Look to your generateRandomString(); and make sure you store a string in your $generatePass variable.

Comment: The function does return a string ^^